# Bootstrap 3 Calendar alignment issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am having bootstrap calendar inside an HTML table as follows. Table is generating dynamically. 
[image]

When the page loads calendar automatically shown as in the picture. I have written the js code as follows.

```
$(".startdate").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you replicate this issue in `jsfiddle`?

Comment: I have not used Fiddler Yet.. So don't know how to use it

Comment: then can you share your full `html` code